# Java 7 - simple object to hold static values and shared methods

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

You have some object that just contains static data and static methods. Lets call it `DataHoldingClass`. You want this because the data is then easily accessible in code by writing `object.VALUE` and `object.method()`. It's all just for laziness and simplicity. And we all agree that this is important.

But some of the `static method()`s are common in your code, so you want to share them among `DataHoldingClass`es. The OOP approach is to define some `abstract class BaseClass`, put common methods there and then let the `DataHoldingClass extends BaseClass`.

But it's not possible, because each `DataHoldingClass` has different values and you cannot reach that values from `abstract class`. If you define `public static final String VALUE` in abstract, all subclasses would have only one shared `VALUE` and if you define separate `VALUE` in each `DataHoldingClass`es, you cannot create `static String method() { return NAME; }` in abstract class, because `NAME` isn't defined in abstract yet.

The only way to make it work is create values and methods non-static. Then the methods will be inherited from `abstract class BaseClass` and will work with `DataHoldingClass` specific values. But now you have to create new class instance every time you want access the data. Hmm, we've advanced from splash to mud.

But we can solve it, right? Just create some object to hold instances or make the `DataHoldingClass` a singleton. But this does not seem to be much better.

Another way might be to pass values to static methods by parameter, but calling some object method with the same object values as parameter seem weird and remember, we do this because of laziness, so we don't want to write object name two times.

Whats your way to storing such data objects? Currently, I'm using singletons, but I feel there must be some better way. Any idea?

## Edit

*example of usage*:

Lets create such `DataHoldingClass` for each table in our database. Each table has own constants like `COLUMN_ID = "_id"` and `TABLE_NAME = "evilTable"` and every table have methods like `insert()` or `update()`. The methods are same for every table but can be overriden for some tables. The Constants are different. And I want define it as constants, because it is then easily accessible like `Table.TABLE_NAME` etc.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on the goal of you `DataHoldingClass`? It might help to separate the constants from the methods, for example, depening on our goal.

Comment: You could create an Enum with properties.

Comment: I'd probably use CDI application scoped beans for that but singletons aren't _that_ bad - that is if you can't change your overall design and remove the requirements for central values/methods etc. The problem I am having (and others as well as it seems) is: what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: create a nonstatic `DataHoldingHelperClass` that can be extended

Comment: @BetaRide Enums would be great, even if it could be extended. Since it's final, I don't see much use for them.

Comment: Enums can implement interfaces. This leaves you with some DRY code. But most of the time it's just setting a property in a constructor and writing a getter. Every decent IDE generates this for free.

Comment: @BetaRide I tried Enum, but you cannot access `Enum.values()` in Interface, nor can you create Enum instance variable in Interface to work with in Interface methods.

Comment: I feel as if this question is something like "How do I encapsulate", obviously if there is a constant you can just make a constants class. The standard libraries do this all the time. For example KeyCodes class where its just a bunch of constants. Just split the constants out of your abstract class and make a new constants class with a specific name

Comment: @Ya Wang That's what I'm doing now. But do you know, how it is when the programming language seem to not fit to your approach and you feel there must be some better way. I think that my question is more like "What Would James Gosling Do" :)